# How to display a datagrid in a new window (using callprint) but with CSS formatting?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, datagrid

Datagrid displays in new window with the javascript function callprint but losers all css formatting. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you really believe that you have provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

- Don't call the datagrid to display in new window.

Or

- Create a page which contains the datagrid and contains the CSS and use javascript to open this window.